# Surround text range with a tag by just specifying the start and end index of characters

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for surrounding range of text of a paragraph by specifying the start and end index of characters of the text range I'm looking to surround.

Example:
`<div id="my_text_area">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>`

By specifying the start index to be `18` and the end index to be `26` of the text range I want to surround, I need JavaScript to update the content to be:
`<div id="my_text_area">Lorem ipsum dolor <span id="my_sub_selection">sit amet</span>, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>`

I prefer not using libraries.

Comment: And you have tried? And what part of what you have tried is not working? And you prefer not to use libraries but instead to have someone else just do it for you. And this is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 1):

If your original html is as simple as the one you posted then you can just create a range use the inner text node when specifying start/end position.

```js
var node = document.querySelector('#my_text_area').childNodes[0],
    start = 18,
    end = 26;
    
    
var range = document.createRange();
range.setStart(node, start);
range.setEnd(node, end);

var wrap = document.createElement('span');
wrap.id = 'my_sub_selection';

range.surroundContents( wrap );
```

```css
#my_sub_selection{background:yellow;}
```

```html
<div id="my_text_area">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
```

---

Once you start having other tags in the `#my_text_area` it starts getting complicated.

Perhaps using a library like [Rangy](https://github.com/timdown/rangy/wiki) is better for this case.

Answer (score 0):

Until you find something shorter (which there is 100% something shorter), the below will do the trick.

I added 2 inputs which are not getting validated so make sure to enter valid values. I leave validation to you if needed.

Clicking the mark button will highlight the text from-to the values you entered.

The below code also removes the existing selection first before applying the new one.

Again, this is convoluted code and can be shortened and optimized 100%. Just intended to get you started.

```js
document.getElementById('mark').addEventListener('click', function(){
  var start = document.getElementById('startIndex').value;
  var stop = document.getElementById('stopIndex').value;;
  markText(--start, --stop);
})

var markText = function(start, stop) {
  var markerTemplate = '<span id="my_sub_selection">{0}</span>';
  var element = document.getElementById('my_text_area');
  
  var data = element.innerHTML;
  
  data = removeMark(data);
  
  data = data.replace(data.substring(start, stop), markerTemplate.replace('{0}', data.substring(start, stop)));

  element.innerHTML = data;
}

var removeMark = function(data){
    var subSelect = document.getElementById('my_sub_selection');
    
    if(subSelect == undefined){
      return data;
    }

  var currentSelection = subSelect.outerHTML;
  var selectedText = subSelect.innerHTML;

  return data.replace(currentSelection, selectedText);
}
```

```css
#my_sub_selection {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<input id="startIndex" />
<input id="stopIndex" />
<button id="mark" type="button">mark text</button>

<div id="my_text_area">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
```